# What is lvmid in java?

Tags: java

I'm learning how to use jps, and I find this page: [jps](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html). It says that:

> The lvmid is typically, but not necessarily, the operating system's process identifier for the JVM process.

So I'm wondering in what situation jps is not the operating system's process identifier?

Anyone would help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do all operating systems have the notion of a "process ID"? Maybe not. Some of them may even represent process IDs, not as Integers, but in an entirely different form. Process IDs are a platform specific concept and could change in the future. Java is designed to be platform-independent. This is why it may not always work.

However, on all major operating systems currently in use today, the `lvmid` should always return the operating system's process ID for the JVM process.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question. I think your answering do make sense.

Comment: Would love to have more info, and on what operating systems, the `lvmid` is guaranteed to match the `pid`. Reason is scripts that start and stop background services running in Java - they would need to fetch the `pid`, and looking it up with `ps` command could fail due to long classpath declarations, whereas getting the `pid` using `jps` is guaranteed to work (except if `lvmid <> pid` !!!).

Answer (score 1):

It's basically saying that the lvmid is typically the same as the O/S pid (process id), but that it doesn't have to be the same.  Some operating systems might differentiate between them (I don't know which ones).

Answer (score 0):

I discovered today that a java process running on CygWin versus running on a native Linux machine would have a different lvmid than pid.  This caused my script to search for the lvmid to shutdown the Java process to fail in that I was passing the incorrect pid.

As you can see from my pic, the lvmid is 6704 but the pid is 19248

[image]